# Find x, y coordinates of a curve by knowing only 3 points?

Tags: geometry

I was wondering if it's possible to find other coordinates of a curve if I know only 3 points? [The points that I know are (1,5), (5.5, 25), (8,50)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkoZ0.png) The curve is exponential I think. It's actually the formula for making a tea. The narrator of a book says that the bigger the container, the less ingredients I will need. In this case, ingredients is x and container size is y

What if I want to find x when the container size = 10 (x, 10)? Is there a formula for this?

Comment: Ummm... depends on the functional form of the curve, of course.

Comment: Generally speaking, no.  Three points will determine a conic section, but not higher order curves.

Comment: "the bigger the container, the less ingredients I will need". Your graph suggests that the bigger the container, the *more* ingredients you'll need, which would make more sense.

Comment: @AdamRubinson That's true if you work out the percentage of the first and second points. The percentage is decreased on the third point though.

Comment: Yes but you never said anything about percentages. Nick - You need to be more precise in your comments and questions. Don't leave information out, and also be more precise in what you say and ask.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a figure is worth 1000 words:

[image]

If you *know* the functional form is $a + b e^{c t}$, then it is a simple exercise in nonlinear model fitting to get:  $$-5.2 + 8.01 e^{0.24 t}$$

[image]

Comment: It's an exponential curve I think. It's actually the formula for making a tea. The narrator of a book says that the bigger the container, the less ingredients I will need. In this case, ingredients is x and container size is y

Comment: @NickB You should have included that information in your question...

Comment: Edited Thanks @AdamRubinson

Answer (score 0):

The general form of an exponential equation is $y = A + Be^{cx}$.

Given three coordinates that the curve must pass through, we plug in each coordinate into the equation.

This gives us a system of three equations with three unknowns, $A, B$ and $C$, which we should be able to solve and thus determine the specific values of $A, B$ and $C$, which in turn tells us the specific exponential function that our curve satisfies.